# Protecticting node.js server using Azure AD OAuth 2.0

Tags: node.js, azure, oauth, active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I wrote a little server in node.js and deployed it to Azure WebApp. I want to add service-to-service authentication using Azure AD OAuth (like this [flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645543.aspx)). I alredy did this in another WebApi sevice using Katana. 

So, I found the [official](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad) library for this, and it work great. The only problem is that the library use the ursa module, which is a native module. And, like explained [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/) it is not easy to deploy a WebApp with native modules.

So, my question is - what is the best approach? How I could accomplish authentication using Azure AD OAuth?

Thanks,

Omer

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Authentication / Authorization feature of Azure Web Apps. It allows you to do OAuth 2.0 service-to-service auth flows using Azure AD, no code changes necessary (also, it works with any stack, not just node.js).

More high-level info here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/13/azure-websites-authentication-authorization/

The post is a bit dated and doesn't mention the recently added support for APIs, but if your client can acquire an OAuth token from Azure AD, you can send it to your node.js server as a bearer token in the `Authorization` header of your HTTP request and have the authorization just work.

Two things to be aware of if you go down this route:

1. Authentication / Authorization currently blocks ALL unauthenticated access to your node.js API. You won't be able to say that some APIs are protected and some are not.
2. The JWT token that you send to your node.js API must use the client_id GUID value as the value for the "aud" claim. Using the app URI (as shown in some Azure AD samples) will not work.

Give it a try and see if it works for you.

Comment: I know this feature, and already try it out. The main problem with this, as they say in the link you added, "Head less authentication/authorization for API scenarios or service to service scenarios are not currently supported.". The ApiApp have better support, but I have problems when I try to configure it.

Comment: @omer, as I mentioned the link is old, headless authentication is supported today. It's just not documented yet.

Comment: OK, I think I tried it out, but I will give it another try.

Comment: OK, I checked it again. WebApp authorization not working with head less authentication (Or at least passing an Authorization header with token is not working). I used the client_id as the AUD.